# DAX Query for getting Total customer who made first Purchase

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am new to the power BI - DAX queries , Could you please help me to solve the below problem.

I have Customer Data in Excel with following columns, I need to find out total number of customer who made first purchase for the Date and Month using DAX query:
Columns are - DateFirstPurchase,CustomerKey,FirstName,lastName

[CustomerData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfSJx.png)

I am looking for output like below :-

```
DateFirstPurchase   Number of Customer
   Jan 11             2
```

etc.....

```
**Sample Customer Data in Excel sheet :**
DateFirstPurchase   CustomerKey FirstName   last Name
1/11/2004 0:00      11602   Larry   Gill
4/21/2004 0:00      12517   Alexa   Watson
2/2/2004 0:00       12518   Jacquelyn   Dominguez
1/20/2004 0:00      12714   Colleen Lu
5/12/2004 0:00      12871   Leah    Li
1/11/2004 0:00      13830   Andrea  Cox
3/14/2004 0:00      13838   Jill    Rubio
2/2/2004 0:00       14839   Natasha Sanz
8/25/2003 0:00      14840   Autumn  Zhu
11/12/2002 0:00     14848   George  Louverdis
10/12/2003 0:00     16453   Mayra   Chandra
2/2/2004 0:00       16458   Michele Ruiz
12/17/2003 0:00     16460   Jodi    Xu
2/11/2002 0:00      18038   Kelli   Kumar
8/25/2003 0:00      19371   Roy     Mehta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this measure

```
Measure =
COUNTROWS (
    EXCEPT (
        VALUES ( 'Table'[CustID] ),
        SUMMARIZE (
            FILTER (
                ALL ( 'Table' ),
                'Table'[DateFirstPurchase] < MAX ( 'Table'[DateFirstPurchase] )
            ),
            'Table'[CustID]
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thankyou for the query. I tried this query and it works fine but the data in the added column is showing the same value (sum of total first purchases) for all the rows. Any idea if I am missing something.

Comment: You need to use this as a measure and not column. Create a measure with this. In the viz bring the date axis and drop the measure

Comment: Thankyou its working now

Comment: Can you please accept the answer.

Comment: Thankyou I have accepted the solution

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new table:

[image]

And use a code like this to calculate the new table:

```
new_table = SUMMARIZE('existing_table', 'existing_table'[DateFirstPurchase].[MonthNo], 'existing_table'[DateFirstPurchase].[Year], "Number of customers", COUNTROWS('existing_table'))
```

**The result** would look like:

[image]

If you want to have a column with values like `2019 - 12`, `2017 - 11` you could add a new column into the created table:

```
Month = 'new_table'[Year] & " - " & 'new_table'[MonthNo]
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Update,** you could also do it in **Power Query**:

Rightclick on the date column

[image]

After that `Transform` -> `Group by`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time and response. I used the above steps and created a new table and I am getting the required output in my report. But when I tried to save the report the data in the new table is getting blank i.e., not showing the values. is their any other way I can achieve the output by 'add column' in the given table itself so that I can save the data.

Comment: Ok. This sound special, this tables shouldn't disappear after saving. 
if you want to create a new column, you probably could use the same formula from the measure smpa01 provided. 
But try to figure out why the data is getting blank. This doesn't make sense at all, or it shouldn't be like this at all.

Comment: Thankyou I will try to figure out.